# How to tail docker into jq?

Tags: bash, docker, jq

I'm trying to pipe json logs from docker into `jq`.
It works fine if I use:

```
docker logs container_id 2>&1 | jq '.'
```

But, if I try to tail it, it gets stuck (displaying nothing).

```
docker logs -f container_id 2>&1 | jq '.'
```

While tailing by itself does work:

```
docker logs -f container_id 2>&1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe?

Comment: The log files are stored on the file system of the container host in JSON format. To determine the location of the JSON file(s) you can run: docker inspect [container] | grep LogPath

Comment: Perhaps it has to be streamed in? I don't know how the output differs in docker but perhaps you could use the jq's `--stream` option and use the [`streaming`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Streaming) filters to work with the data.

Comment: [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) is pertinent.

Comment: ...well, *probably* pertinent. Let's say you replace `jq` with `cat`; do you have the same issue? If so, your issue is that `docker logs` is buffering its stdout when not written to a TTY (which is default libc behavior, and thus common to many if not most applications!).

Comment: BTW, `jq --unbuffered` is needed to stop `jq` from doing the same when *its* stdout is written to a non-TTY sink.

Comment: Buffering seems like the likely cause, but I'm not able to reproduce the issue with `$ docker run -d --rm --name tail-test busybox /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo '{\"hello\": \"world\"}'; sleep 2; done"; docker logs -f tail-test | jq .`. Are you able to provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of tailing from stdout you might want to tail the log file that is stored in the container directory.

Docker stores logs for each container under `/var/lib/docker/containers/[container_ID]`, you can find the container ID using `docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" container_name`

then use tail and jq as you would normally.

```
tail -f  /var/lib/docker/containers/[container_ID]/[container_ID]-json.log | jq '.'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Nic3500 thank you for the feedback I've improved the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Although the default (`json-file`) logging driver uses JSON as a *file format*, the `docker logs` command does not output JSON, but plain text, so if you use jq, you would have to use the -R option to read it.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. `docker logs` outputs my stdout. My application within the container already outputs JSON... That's not the issue. As I said, if I don't use `-f` it works fine.